# How to receive get parameter in viewset in django restframe work?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

For the part of developing an API using restframe work and DJango, I need to receive few parameters through get method in 'list' function of my Viewset. In client side they are sending data as query prams, I somehow managed to get the data using 'request.query_params.get()'  but received data is text format instead of bool, I had to convert this to boolean . see the code how  I did this

```
if 'status' in (request.query_params):
                """receiving input argument is string need to convert that to boolean for further processing"""
                input_status=(request.query_params.get('status', None)=='true')
```

is there any better way to getting data without losing datatype. is it possible to receive 'bool' or 'int' values directly in get parameter?

My model and view set classes are given below

```
class ModuleType(models.Model):
          
    """
    This module type class used to represent each module of the application. It is inherited from
    django content type which holds the complete model informations
    """
    #this active field is true this module will be active on our user controller
    content_type = models.OneToOneField(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='status',
        null=True       
    )
    active=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'module_types'







My Viewset

class ContentTypeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       
    """
    This api deals all operations related with module management
    You will have `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    update` and `destroy` actions.
    Additionally we also provide an action to update status.
       """
    queryset = ContentType.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContentTypeSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    """
     Over ride list method to list values
    """
    def list(self, request):
       
        status='Sucess'
        message='details of all modules included'
        print(request)
        try:
            if 'status' in (request.query_params):
                #input argument is striing need to convert that to boolean 
                input_status=(request.query_params.get('status', None)=='true')
                validated_value= self.validate_input_params({'status':input_status})
                if (validated_value==1): 
                    all_modules = ContentType.objects.filter(status__active=input_status)
                    message='All value set status as '+str(input_status)
                else:
                    message='Failed to validate all input values'
                    status='fail'
                    return Response({"status":status,"data":[],"message":message})                    
            else:
                all_modules=ContentType.objects.all()
            serializer = self.get_serializer(
                all_modules,
                many=True
                )
            return Response({"status":status,"data":serializer.data,'message':message})
        except:
            message='unknown exception'
            status='Fail'
            return Response({"status":status,"data":[],"message":message})
```

Comment: No, you can't *keep the data type* between client and server

Answer (score 0):

Your view will read query params as string.

I suggest you use `query_params = dict(request.GET.items())`

That way you can parse parameters easier by using dict.

Comment: Still data type is string, I need to convert boolean to process data

Comment: As I said, it will always be read as string. This way just helps you to iterate over keys.

Comment: Feel free to accept that answer if you feel it has helped you enough ;)

Comment: Bro, Thanks for the support, But that wasn't answer for the question I asked, I know the function you mentioned early, I think Arakkal Abu  answer helped me more